# C# How/Possible to add new property to existing class dynamically or with class extension?

Tags: c#, dynamically-generated, class-extensions

So, I have an object, and it would be very beneficial if I could include a reference to another object within this object upon its creation.

In this specific circumstance the class that is being used is:
`Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle`

So the way I was trying to do this was the following, I do not have that much knowledge about C#, been studying it now for 3 months. So it is very likely the way I am trying to do this is far from optimal. But I hope that the following examples will display what I am trying to do.

The first way was to simply try adding the property dynamically:

```
var rectangle = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle();
object obj = new object();
rectangle._obj = obj;
```

The second way was to try and extend the class, and then using my own constructor.

```
class My_Rectangle : Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle {
    private object _obj;
    public My_Rectangle(object obj) {
        _obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Then I would simply create the object like this:

```
object obj = new object();
var myRectangle = new My_Rectangle(obj);
```

I personally didn't have much hope for either of these methods... So I am turning to this community hoping to achieve some sense of clarity on how I can do this.

If I was unclear or it seems I was unspecific, consider my inexperience and request that I clarify.

Best regards!

Edit:
I found out about the Tag property, and this seems to do the trick.

```
var rectangle = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle();
object obj = new object();
rectangle.Tag = obj;
```

If there is a way to perform my original question, that'd still be appreciated though :)

Answer (score 1):

In many scenarios your 2nd option (`class MyRectangle: Rectangle`) would work.

However, `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle` is a sealed: `public sealed class Rectangle : Shape`. This means that other classes are forbidden from inheriting from it. Please see [sealed (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) for more info.

You could reverse what you do and have a class that stores extra information and have the rectangle too.

```
class RectangleAndX
{
  public Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }
  public ClassX X { get; set;}
}
```

BTW. You generally need to avoid working with `object` type, especially at the beginning of your progamming journey.

Comment: Thank you, this is really good to know. I have a decent amount of experience in javascript and quite comfy with the whole concept of objects and such. C# has quite a few differences though. But the term "object", as I use it. Was just for this specific example. The actual code references the "object" as "Item", which is the class in question. And in general, I do think that deep diving into things you don't fully understand is the best way to learn, for me. I'll look at the link regarding sealed.